# Trying to Replace ' with literal C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, literals

I have a Little Problem here. Im trying to replace the Character ' with \'

I tried string replace method in the following ways:

1.

```
string test = "HISTOIRE D'O, CHAPITRE II";
test = test.Replace("'","\'");
```

Nothing Changed in the String test is the same as declared

2.

```
string test = "HISTOIRE D'O, CHAPITRE II";
test = test.Replace("'","\\'");
```

This Formats my string like this "HISTOIRE D\\'O, CHAPITRE II";

Found nothing yet on Google etc.

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this? If it's to avoid SQL injection, you should use parameterized SQL instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second code is correct.

> This Formats my string like this "HISTOIRE D\'O, CHAPITRE II";

No, it really doesn't. That's how it looks *in the debugger*, but if you dump it to a console or something similar, you'll see there's only a single backslash.

As an alternative, you could use a verbatim string literal:

```
test = test.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second case seems correct. Looks like this is only how looks like in degubber. Try to write on console and you will see the expected result.

[image]

You can use *[verbtaim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* instead;

```
string test = "HISTOIRE D'O, CHAPITRE II";
test = test.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is working, but when you look at the result in the debugger it "helpfully" escapes the backslash by adding a new backslash to it.

If you print the result to a console window you should see what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = test.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
string test = "HISTOIRE D'O, CHAPITRE II";
test = test.Replace("'", @"\'");
```